# Android Studio Gradle Issue: OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After several hours of fighting to get an older project imported from Eclipse to use Gradle and into Android Studio v0.1.3...what I've gotten to now is I can actually do the build on the command line, but when I do Build/Rebuild Project *in* Studio I get:

```
Gradle: 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':EpicMix'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':facebook'.
      > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
         > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

It's not a HUGE project, there's a few small sub-projects (including Facebook), so I don't think it really is memory.  I just can't figure out what this is...

Answer (score 115):

For those of you running gradle from the command line, create a **gradle.properties** file, put it in the root of your project, and add the following:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: and remove already existing "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms128m -Xmx512m" or similar line if necessary

Comment: dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
} in gradle worked for me

Comment: You should restart Android Stuio after setting MaxPermSize! Thanks :)

Answer (score 43):

The size of the PermGen space can be increased within Android Studio under File > Settings > Compiler. Look for the setting named "Additional compiler process VM options". Just add the following parameter:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

The default value is 92M. Use G if you want to specify a value in gigabytes.

Comment: Thanks Soren, do you know how to set this for a gradle build?

Comment: To set it for a gradle build in Android Studio, put the `-XX:MaxPermSize` argument into VM options on the Run / Debug Configurations.

Answer (score 14):

If you are on Mac OS X it's possible to increase MaxPermSize inside file

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/bin/idea.vmoptions
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for this for quite a while!

Comment: Note, Google recommends against doing this in the latest versions of the IDE. See my answer for what they recommend doing now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30253323/1654145

Answer (score 12):

The recommended way of setting JVM arguments, such as max PermGen size, is by following the advice given here - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

**Android Studio 2.0 and newer**

As of Android Studio 2.0, there is an option to access the configuration file directly from the IDE.

Use the `Help->Edit Custom VM Options` menu.
[image]

Taken from the configuration page, the full set of JVM arguments are as follows, alongs with their default values:

`-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops`

**Legacy Instructions:**

You should create your own ***studio.vmoptions*** file and put your JVM settings in here. The location of your file should be:

> - Mac OS **~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/studio.vmoptions**
> - Linux **~/.AndroidStudio/studio.vmoptions** (or ~/.AndroidStudio/studio64.vmoptions)
> - Windows: **%USERPROFILE%.AndroidStudio\studio.exe.vmoptions** (or %USERPROFILE%.AndroidStudio\studio64.exe.vmoptions)

Note, you should no longer edit the files in the AndroidStudio app directory as these will be overwritten with each new installation/update to the IDE.

Comment: How is your menu bar so beautifully blue?

Comment: You know what... I have no idea why it was that colour! It isn't like that now for me in my current version of Android Studio.

Comment: You're using the dark theme, I am too. It just looks more blue than black. Jealous.

Answer (score 4):

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000841/jenkins-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space) worked for me - if you're in Linux, just set the environment variable GRADLE_OPTS to be "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m" (or whatever size you want).

Answer (score 2):

You can have a `gradle.properties` file and then add the following.

Create or edit the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` to include the following

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your *gradle.properties*:

```
 org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

At every build or clean several java processes are started causing Out of Memory errors.

Brute force solution:

Kill java.exe processes before any build or run. This will have side effects on any other active application working with java.

[Android Studio 1.4 - JRE 1.7.0_75-b13]

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac go to ~/.gradle and delete both the caches and daemon folders. These get regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gradle build file add the following jvmArgs inside test {} block to increase the perm-gen space allocation:

```
test {
    jvmArgs "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
}
```

Comment: Could not find method "jvmArgs"