# How to Increase the Memory that's available to gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In the [official post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ng/2016/04/android-studio-21-supports-android-n.html) detailing the features of the stable release of Android Studio 2.1, I came across this:

> We are also speeding up build times by using in-process dex, which converts class files to dex files within the Gradle daemon process. This avoids the costly processing operation of creating separate dex processes. To use this feature, you will need to **increase the amount of memory available to the Gradle daemon to at least 2GB (1 GB is the default)**.

Please, how can I increase the memory that's available to Gradle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle Issue: OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012619/android-studio-gradle-issue-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your app's `build.gradle` file, add the following:

```
android{
     //....
     dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to use this as settngs, not to add to every project?

Answer (score 18):

In Android Studio 2.1 open your gradle.properties file. Find the line

```
\# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Uncomment the line. Gradle was faster after I did this.

Answer (score 3):

I have not try this but it should works:

In graddle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    //raise heap
    options.fork = 'true'
    options.forkOptions.with {
        memoryMaximumSize = '2048m'
    }
}
```

If it does not work in Windows try to add it to a new file *gradle.properties* next to *gradle.build*

References: http://www.gubatron.com/blog/2014/07/29/solved-gradle-how-to-increase-the-java-compilers-available-heap-memory/

I hope it helps you

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please include the relevant text and code from the link in your answer.

Comment: small nitpick but your quotes are stylized quotes and not standard ASCII quotes. makes for bad copy-paste.